# fresh LAMP install on AWS EC2, cannot access Laravel internal links

Tags: laravel, apache

The out-of-the-box `welcome.php` works well giving me the home page, yet internal links such as login or register return a 404.

I do not get any apache error in the log.
I've read many questions here that relate to my issue with no avail.

From googling this issue, I'm assuming it has to do with the conf file, but maybe im wrong, so feel free to ask for more info.

#### conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/testing/public_html/public
    serverName www.example.com
    serverAlias example.com
<Directory /var/www/testing/public_html/public>
    AllowOverride All
    allow from all
    options +Indexes
    Require all granted
</Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If I'm not getting any errors, how can I debug this? I would be happy to learn in the process.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that I had to execute `sudo a2enmod rewrite`.